# C# Streamwriter - Problem with the encoding

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core, encoding, .net-6.0

I have some product data that I want to write into a csv file. First I have a function that writes the header into the csv file:

```
using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    string[] headerContent = {"banana","apple","orange"};
    string header = string.Join(",", headerContent);
    streamWriter.WriteLine(header);
}
```

Another function goes over the products and writes their data into the csv file:

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(product.ToString());
    }
}
```

When writing the products into the csv file and do it with `FileMode.Open` and `Encoding.UTF8`, the encoding is set correctly into the file meaning that special characters in german or french get shown correctly. But the problem here is that I overwrite my header when I do it like this.

The solution I tried was to not use `FileMode.Open` but to use `FileMode.Append` which works, but then for some reason the encoding just gets ignored.

What could I do to append the data while maintaing the encoding? And also why is this happening in the first place?

**EDIT:**

Example with `FileMode.Open`:

Fußpflegecreme

Example with `FileMode.Append`:

FuÃŸpflegecreme

Comment: _" the encoding just gets ignored"_ What makes you think it gets ignored? Please explain showing examples. You've missed the most important details.

Comment: When I do it with `FileMode.Open` it shows the characters like é or ö. With `FileMode.Append` instead of showing those characters it shows gibberish. So I  must assume that the encoding gets ignored or not applied.

Comment: "it shows" - where does it show? what **exactly** are you doing to look? I've just run a quick test in a console using `Create` first then `Append`, and it worked just fine - encoding applied correctly. I wonder if the real problem here is that the file doesn't have a BOM, and whatever you're using to look at the data: doesn't expect UTF8 by default. One option there may be to ensure that the first fragment contains a BOM, but honestly: most UTF8 text files *don't use a BOM*

Comment: @MarcGravell I use Excel to open the csv file. When opening it with Visual Studio Code it warns me with a message that this file contains many non-basic ascii unicode characters. In VS Code the Encoding is set to UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: @Florent but *does it actually contain a BOM*? the easiest way to find out is to read the first 3 **bytes** of the file (using a binary tool, not a text tool)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes I just checked it with HxD. The first three bytes are `EF BB BF`. As I have read from your answer, this should be correct

Comment: @MarcGravell Also when removing the Encoding from the function that writes the header, those bytes are not there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be solved once you explicitly choose the utf8 encoding when writing the header. This will prefix the file with a BOM.

Answer (score 1):

The important question here is: what does the file *actually contain*; for example, if I use the following:

```cs
using System.Text;

string path = "my.txt";
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("Fußpflegecreme 1");
}
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("Fußpflegecreme 2");
}
// this next line is lazy and inefficient; only good for quick tests
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes(path)));
```

then the output is (re-formatted a little):

```
EF-BB-BF-
46-75-C3-9F-70-66-6C-65-67-65-63-72-65-6D-65-20-31-0D-0A-
46-75-C3-9F-70-66-6C-65-67-65-63-72-65-6D-65-20-32-0D-0A
```

The first line (note: there aren't any "lines" in the original hex) is the UTF-8 BOM; the second and third lines are the correctly UTF-8 encoded payloads. It would help if you could show the exact bytes that get written in your case. I wonder if the real problem here is that in your version, there is no BOM, but the rest of the data is correct. Some tools, in the absence of a BOM, will choose the wrong encoding. But also, some tools: *in the presence of a BOM*: will incorrectly show some garbage at the start of the file (and may also, because they're clearly not using the BOM: use the wrong encoding). The preferred option is: specify the encoding explicitly when *reading* the file, and use a tool that can handle the presence of absence of a BOM.

Whether or not to include a BOM (especially in the case of UTF-8) is a complex question, and there are pros/cons of each - and there are tools that will work better, or worse, with each. A lot of UTF-8 text files *do not* include a BOM, but: there is no universal answer. The actual content is still correctly UTF-8 encoded whether or not there is a BOM - but how that is interpreted (in either case) is up to the specific tool that you're using to read the data (and how that tool is configured).

Comment: Thanks for your input it really helped.